# Export/Import a SharePoint List/Document Library

Tags: wss-3.0, wss

I'd like to be able to export/import (or backup/restore) lists and document libraries only, with versioning and access rights.

If it is a custom list (deployed via feature), I understand that the feature needs to be deployed prior to import (or restore).

I can't use "save as template", as the list is too big to include content.

stsadm -o export doesn't seem to be able to do this. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SharePoint [Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) should be able to do what you want.

Comment: If anyone interested, there is an [alternative way by using stsadm commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229338/export-a-survey-in-sharepoint-2007-to-a-different-site-collection/6329133#6329133).

Answer (score 1):

YOu can export a list by going to the list settings and then click the save as template link (you can choose to include / exclude content). The template is then usable for creating new lists, but can also be downloaded as an stp file.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a size limit

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I performed the task of exporting a list from 2007 and importing that list to 2010.

- 1) in 2007, go to your top level site in your web part. Modify
  settings-> galleries-> list templates. click the list template you
  want to export, save to disk.
- 2) change the stp to a cab extension.
  export the manifest.xml. change the version from 3 to 4 in the .xml
  (close to the top of the file.). create a new cab file using the
  makecab file.
- 3) rename extension of cab file to stp.
- 4)go into 2010
  web app, top site, site settings-> gallery-> list templates -> insert
  the new stp. create a new list using that template.

Comment: thanks for the update, but the question was 2007 to 2007 (migrated from SO). I updated the tags. Your answer will still be useful to know !